# How to style a graph according to the direction of the edges and the centrality of the vertices?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, visualization

I'm new to Mathematica and I'm using it to study graph theory and network data processing and analysis. I recently started to deal with graph data visualization and directed graphs. Which lead me to the wonder about ways of presenting directed graphs.

Lets suppose the following graph:

```
vlist = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
vrules = {1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 1 -> 5, 2 -> 1, 2 -> 4, 2 -> 5, 3 -> 2, 4 -> 1, 4 -> 5, 5 -> 3, 5 -> 4}
g=Graph[vlist,vrules]
```

Which is rendered as follows:

[image: graph]

Now I want to make bidirectional connections to be presented as a thick line with arrowheads in both ends, single direction connections to be presented with a thin line and the arrowhead indicating its direction.

I also want the vertices to reflect the centrality of the nodes, so nodes with higher centrality would be presented bigger in proportion to its centrality up to a maximum size.

Fo example, the betweeness and degree centralities of this graph are:

```
BetweennessCentrality[g]
{2., 3.5, 1., 1., 1.5}

DegreeCentrality[g]
{5, 5, 3, 4, 5}
```

I've looked into the documentation but didn't find much insight on how to do this kind of stuff, I know that I essentially have to deal with GraphStyle options, but most of them are either poorly documented or not documented at all.

Regards and thanks in advance,

Comment: Have you considered making all bidirectional connections explicit?  Instead of having `4 -> 5` and `5 -> 4` as edges, instead use `4 <-> 5`

Comment: `@Jason B.`, Thanks  for your reply, it would be a very helful helpful option, but only address 1/3 of the problem.

Answer (score 4):

A bit more styling:

```
color[x_, minmax_] := ColorData[{"GrayTones", "Reverse"}][Rescale[x, minmax, {.1, 1}]];

iEShapeFunction[UndirectedEdge[x_, y_], {vsrule_, vstyle_}, dcheck_:True] := 
  With[{sback = {vsrule[x], vsrule[y]}, acolor = {vstyle[x], vstyle[y]}}, 
   ({If[TrueQ[dcheck] && dcheck[x] != #[[1]], sback = Reverse[sback]; 
      acolor = Reverse[acolor]];Blend[acolor, Divide @@ Reverse[sback]], 
      Arrowheads[{-.05, .05}], Thickness[.01], 
      Arrow[Line[#, VertexColors -> acolor], sback]} &)];

iEShapeFunction[DirectedEdge[x_, y_], {vsrule_, vstyle_}, dcheck_:True] := 
  With[{sback = {vsrule[x], vsrule[y]}, acolor = {vstyle[x], vstyle[y]}}, 
   ({Blend[acolor, Divide @@ Reverse[sback]], 
      Arrowheads[{.03}], Thickness[.001], 
      Arrow[Line[#, VertexColors -> acolor], sback]} &)];
```

For example:

```
g = RandomGraph[{15, 35}, DirectedEdges -> True];

dc = DegreeCentrality[g];
{vmin, vmax} = {.02, .15};
vsrule = Association[Thread[VertexList[g] -> Rescale[dc, MinMax[dc], {vmin, vmax}]]];
vstyle = color[#, {vmin, vmax}] & /@ vsrule;
labelstyle = 
  Normal[Directive[White, Bold, Rescale[#, {vmin, vmax}, {8, 20}]] & /@ vsrule];

vlist = VertexList[g];
vcoords = 
  Association[Thread[vlist -> GraphEmbedding[Graph[vlist, edges]]]];

edges = GatherBy[EdgeRules[g], 
    Union] /. {{Rule[x_, y_], Rule[y_, x_]} :> 
     UndirectedEdge[x, y], {Rule[x_, y_]} :> DirectedEdge[x, y]};

Graph[edges, VertexSize -> Normal[{#, #} & /@ vsrule], 
 EdgeStyle -> Blue, VertexStyle -> Normal[vstyle], 
 EdgeShapeFunction -> ((# -> iEShapeFunction[#, {vsrule, vstyle}, vcoords]) & /@
     edges), VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center],
 VertexLabelStyle -> labelstyle
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: `@halmir`, thanks for your help, this is way beyond my expectations and I certainly would spend some time to explore and understand this piece of code, but it would certainly be worth the time.

Answer (score 2):

```
edges=Flatten[GatherBy[vrules, Union] /. {Rule[x_,y_],Rule[y_,x_]}:> 
  Property[UndirectedEdge[x,y], 
    EdgeShapeFunction->({Arrowheads[{-.05, .05}], Thickness[.01], Arrow@#}&)]];

vertices=Property[#,VertexSize->#2]& @@@ Transpose[{vlist,{"Scaled",#/2} & /@ 
   Normalize[DegreeCentrality[Graph[vlist, vrules]], Total]}];

Graph[vertices, edges, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center],
   GraphLayout -> { "RenderingOrder" -> "EdgeFirst"}, 
   EdgeStyle -> Blue, VertexStyle->White]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: `@kglr`, thanks for your help, as always, your answers are interesting and full of stuff to learn while reverse engineering them.

Comment: @nicholas80, my pleasure. Welcome to mma.se.